# ” 'it' was him”. Why do we use 'it' when referring to a person by this object pronoun (him)?

Tags: dummy-it

Why do we use IT together with HIM? Isn't IT only for non-people?

Comment: Non-referential it and referential it are different words in French, which makes this easier. But then your pen and pencil will be of different genders.